# My website can’t be reached, but nothing wrong on GCP

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, bitnami, multisite

> Error message: webiz.johocen.com took too long to respond.

But there is nothing wrong on GCP VM instance.

`ping webiz.johocen.com` got 0% lost 169ms average response

My website is a WordPress multisite on GCP via bitnami. This happened before, reset the VM will solve the problem, but will happen again sometimes later.

Any suggestion where I should look into?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

Sometimes, if you are experiencing poor performance, it is because you are being attacked by Internet bots. The reason for these attacks is that they are trying to find a security bug in your application code or in the software itself.

To know if you are being attacked, run the commands below:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/
tail -n 10000 access_log | awk '{print $1}'| sort| uniq -c| sort -nr| head -n 10
```

This will show you the number of times that an IP address connected to your Web server. If you see that some IP addresses have many more connections than others, run the following command (remember to modify ATTACKER_IP with the correct IP):

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/
grep "ATTACKER_IP" access_log
```

If you see that the IP address is always attempting to connect to the same location, if it is a URL that you don’t know, or if it is trying to run binaries or scripts directly, it is likely that IP address is a bot.

To deny connections to these attackers, the easiest way is with your Apache configuration file. Follow these steps:

Edit the file at /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf. The example below shows how to reject the 1.2.3.4 IP address in WordPress:

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs>
deny from 1.2.3.4
...
</Directory>
```

Restart the Apache web server:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

More information here: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/troubleshooting/deny-connections-bots/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, followed but could not find any ip suspicious, will keep an eye on.